# Perl 5: How to improve regex for URL parsing

Tags: regex, perl, url-parsing

I'm trying to parse a text file of tweets and remove URLs and put them into a urls.txt file. At the moment, I have this regex:

`($line =~ /((?:https?|ftp|telnet|gopher|file|imap):\/\/[\w\-\.\~\!\*\'\(\)\;\:\@\&\=\+\$\,\/\\\?\%\#\[\]]*)/)`

But as I want to build on it further, and it's quite unwieldy even now, I'm wondering if there's any way I can check for [valid URL characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#List_of_allowed_URL_characters) (the `[\w\-\.\~\!\*\'\(\)\;\:\@\&\=\+\$\,\/\\\?\%\#\[\]]*` part) using something like an array or a hash. Or anything that doesn't make it so unnecessarily verbose.

The rest of my code can be provided if needed for whatever reason.

Comment: say more about "want to build on it further"

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ysth Some of those characters aren't valid as part of the domain-name as far as I know.

Comment: @Sobrique Parsing a text file of tweets and extracting all the URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate a URL why not use a module from CPAN to do the hard work for you.

```
my $uri = URI->new("http://www.perl.com");
```

See the details of the `URI` module [here](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/URI-1.64/URI.pm).

As recommended by Sobrique, you could also use:

```
 use Data::Validate::URI qw(is_uri);

 if (is_uri("http://www.perl.com")) {
     ...
 }
```

See the details of the `Data::Validate::URI` module [here](http://search.cpan.org/~sonnen/Data-Validate-URI-0.06/lib/Data/Validate/URI.pm).

Comment: I was looking at `Data::Validate::URI`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. It's for a Script Programming module and the lecturer wants it done using regex.

Comment: Since this is homework you should really fix it yourself :) You can implement the regex correctly by converting a BNF URI parser into a Regex one. All you need to do is convert each simple section (a section that does not refer to another section) into a regular expression, and then create the composite sections by combining the simple ones. You can find a BNF of the URI structure here: http://freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1630/26.htm and a description of the BNF format here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form